# How to use DropDown List with urls

Tags: html

I want to use a drop down list with url, when the user choose an element it will be open like a simple link, this is what I did but it's not working, I still in my current page.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#header-link1").change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
              window.location.href = $(this).val();
            }
          });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <select name="forma" id="header-link1">
      <option value="Select option">
        Select option
      </option>
      <option value="http://www.surtymar.com/fr/reglementation-internationale/">
        Réglementation internationale 15
      </option>
      <option value="http://www.surtymar.com/fr/reglementation-union-europeenne/">
        Réglementation 15
      </option>

    </select>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 'It's not working' doesn't tell us enough to help you. Please provide a) the results you are expecting, b) the results you are getting, c) any error messages. Thanks.

Comment: no error, I click and nothing happend, I still in my current page

Comment: you want redirect to another page once user clicks?

Comment: I can't see anything in the code that the user can click, or anything that handles that click, you need to add more of your code to what you have posted.

Comment: I edited right now you can see @MandyShaw

Comment: Looks like you're ok now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:-

Use `JQuery` to achive this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#header-link1").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()!='') {
      window.location.href=$(this).val();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form >
            <select name="forma" id="header-link1" >
         <option value="Select option">
            Select option
        </option>
        <option value="http://www.surtymar.com/fr/reglementation-internationale/">
            Réglementation internationale 15
        </option>
        <option value="http://www.surtymar.com/fr/reglementation-union-europeenne/">
              Réglementation 15
        </option>
        
        </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: thank's but it's not working, I edited my post to see what I did

Comment: Yes you are right, could you see my post where I had a mistake ?

Comment: @StanlyEl you are missing }); at script.

Comment: God bless you bro !

Comment: I did it, really sorry, I'm new here !

Answer (score 1):

Try this! Should work! It just select options value and redirect user!

```
<form >
    <select name="forma" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="http://surtymar.com/fr/reglementation-internationale/">Réglementation internationale 15</option>
        <option value="http://surtymar.com/fr/reglementation-union-europeenne/">Réglementation 15</option>
    </select>
</form>
```